# Give an example of a real inner product space $V$ and $S \in L(V)$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a^2<4b$ with $S^2 + aS + bI$ is not invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

Give an example of a real inner product space $V$ and $S \in L(V)$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a^2<4b$ with $S^2 + aS + bI$ is not invertible.

attempt: Let $S(x,y) = (-y,x)$. be the counterclockwise rotation of $\pi/2$ about the origin. And let $a = 0, b = 4$, then $0< 8$ , and $S^2 + 4I$ . Then if $(S^2 + 4I)v \neq 0$, then $S^2 + 4I$ is injective, which would imply it's invertible.
So we need to show $S^2 + 4I = 0$, so that $S^2 + 4I $ is not invertible.
So if $S^2 + 4I=0$, then $S^2 = -4I$. Can someone please help me? I am confuse how to give the conclusion.
Any feedback would really help. Thank you.

Comment: Presumably, it should be $S^2 + aS + bI$

Comment: Yes it was typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ be the rotation by $\pi/2$.  Then $S^2$ is the $180^\circ$ rotation, which is to say that $S^2 = -I$.  So, $S^2 + I = 0$.

That is, if $a = 0$ and $b = 1$, then we find $0 = a^2 < 4b = 4$, and (for $S$ as above) $S^2 + aS + bI = 0$.  Since $S^2 + aS + bI = 0$, $S^2 + aS + bI$ is not invertible.

Comment: So we just assumed that $ S^2 +4I =0$? Why can we say it's equal to zero ?

Comment: Where do you keep getting this $4I$ from?  No, we did not just assume that.

Comment: Yes , you choose b = 1 . And I choose b=4. Would this value also work ?

Comment: In your case , is it enough to assume that $S^2 + I =0$ ?

Comment: @Mahidevran $b=4$ could work, but **not** for the rotation by $\pi/2$.  I did not **assume** that $S^2 + I = 0$.  After **defining** $S$ to be the rotation by $\pi/2$, I **showed** that $S^2 + I = 0$.

Comment: @Mahidevran if you *assume* that $S$ is the a rotation, then also *assume* that $S^2 + 4I = 0$, then you are assuming two inconsistent statements.